# Can't get data to save in MySQL using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, frameworks, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to get the ticket data to save in the database and when I submit the form I get no error, but it does not insert the data into the database. Added my Route just adding random text because the post

#### Controller Code

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
       'name' => 'required',
        'title' => 'required|min:15',
        'category' => 'required',
        'priority' => 'required',
        'message' => 'required|min:100',
    ]);

    $ticket = new Ticket([
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
        'category_id' => $request->input('category'),
        'ticket_id' => strtoupper(str_random(10)),
        'name' => $request->input('name'),
        'title' => $request->input('title'),
        'priority_id' => $request->input('priority'),
        'message' => $request->input('message'),
    ]);

    $ticket->status_id = '1';
    $ticket->save();

    return 'Success';
}
```

#### Model Code

```
class Ticket extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
      'user_id', 'category_id', 'ticket_id', 'name', 'title', 'priority_id', 'message', 'status_id',
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function priority()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Priority::class);
    }

    public function status()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Status::class);
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Routes

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/compliance', 'HomeController@Compliance')->name('compliance');
Route::get('/messages', 'HomeController@Messages')->name('messages');
Route::get('/tickets', 'TicketsController@userTickets')->name('tickets');
Route::get('/tickets/create', 'TicketsController@create')->name('tickets/create');
Route::post('/tickets/store', 'TicketsController@store');
```

Comment: What is your MySQL table named?

Comment: tickets I already tried to add the following protected $table = 'tickets';

Comment: I saw you posted a response but when I refreshed my page it was gone did you delete the comment?

Comment: Try to add `dd($ticket);` just before your return statement and tell us what it says

Comment: I get nothing once i press the submit button the page just reloads

Comment: Can you show us the code of your view? And any relavant routes from your `routes.php` file

Comment: Just Added it to the post

Comment: Btw the routes posted are located in web.php

Comment: You are probably making some small mistake. Try to debug it with dd (on various places) in your code and you will get to the point where something is not the way you want it to be.

Comment: Is your validation definitely passing?

Comment: @RossWilson Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help I figured it I had two mistakes in the controller this took me 2 days to figure it out LOL

```
        $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required', // I removed this
        'title' => 'required|min:15',
        'category' => 'required',
        'priority' => 'required',
        'message' => 'required|min:100',
    ]);
```

and in the $ticket

```
       $ticket = new Ticket([
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
        'category_id' => $request->input('category'),
        'ticket_id' => strtoupper(str_random(10)),
        'name' => $request->input('name') // I replaced this with 'name' => Auth::user()->name,
        'title' => $request->input('title'),
        'priority_id' => $request->input('priority'),
        'message' => $request->input('message'),
    ]);
```